# How to find a differential equation for the family of circles passing through the origin with the centers on the x-axis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried using $(X-A)^2 +Y^2 = R^2$, differentiated but when I try to get rid of the $A$ constant, the $X$ terms disappear.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In fact the general equation of the circles $C_a$ is $(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$ or

$$\tag{1}x^2+y^2-2ax=0$$

In order to know which circle passes through $(x,y)$, it suffices to extract $a$ from (1), giving

$$\tag{2}a=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2x}$$

Differentiating relationship (1), one gets:

$$(2x-2a)dx+2ydy=0$$

$$\iff \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{a-x}{y}.$$

Using (2):

$$\iff y'=\dfrac{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2x}-x}{y} \ \ \iff \ \ \boxed{y'=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}}$$

Here is a picture obtained by using Wolfram Alpha (instruction StreamPlot[{y^2-x^2,2xy},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}] for the integration of the vector field where one recognizes clearly the family of circles $C_a$:

[image]

Remarks:

1. Let us mention that the set of **orthogonal curves** to curves $C_a$ is (classical property, see for example (http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/ortogonal1.pdf)) obtained by replacing $y'$ by $-1/y'$ in the boxed result. The resulting differential equation $y'=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ has for its solutions the family of circles that can be obtained by a $\pi/2$ rotation of the family $C_a$...
2. There is also another connection with complex function theory. It is not pure coincidence that, in the numerator and the denominator of the solution, one finds the real and imaginary parts of $z^2=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+i(2xy)$, which are called dual harmonic functions. But it would be too long to enter into the subject...
3. For a generalisation, see Apollonian circles (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CoaxalCircles.shtml)

Comment: I have added some remarks at the end of my text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the implicit derivative:

$2(x-a)dx+2ydy=0.$

Divide by $2dx$ and solve for $dy/dx$:

$$dy/dx=\frac{a-x}{y}.$$

Comment: I did do this, the thing is I need to get rid of the constant a.