# Orthogonal path

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the equations of a curve set are expressed in polar form, that is, have
$f(r, θ, dr / dθ) = 0$
Sometimes form differential equations
$f(r, θ, -r ^ 2dθ / dr) = 0$
Is it expressed?

Comment: I want to know how we achieve this result?

Comment: I don't realy understand your english, could explain more please

Comment: I want to know how do we get to this form?
f (r, θ, -r ^ 2dθ / dr)

Comment: Is the following what you mean ? it is in cartesian https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836392/orthogonal-trajectories-elimination-of-constant

Answer (score 0):

This is an intuitive explanation of the perpendicular form of the derivative in polar coordinates.

Take a polar curve $r(\theta)$. At a point on it, take a small increment $\delta\theta$, which results in an arc change of $r\delta\theta$ and a radial change of $\delta r\approx r'(\theta)\delta\theta$.

The perpendicular direction to this is given by a change in arc change of $-\delta r$ and a radial change of $r\delta\theta$. Thus the new curve $R(\Theta)$ must satisfy $\delta R=-r\delta\theta$ and $\delta\Theta=\delta r/r$. Hence $$\frac{dR}{d\Theta}=\frac{-rd\theta}{r^{-1}dr}=-r^2\frac{d\theta}{dr}$$